# 403 Forbidden - These credentials do not authorize access - weather here api forecast_astronomy

Tags: here-api, weather-api, authorize

Using the weather here api with product of forecast_astronomy and now all of sudden getting a 403 forbidden error on the request of "These credentials do not authorize access". The url request has not changed in the code and I have verified in the developer portal that the app id is enabled still.

This was working fine when last tried two days ago.

Tried directly in curl and postman and getting same 403 forbidden error:

{
"error": "Forbidden",
"error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine two reasons:

- you did not verify your email address after registering the account. If that's the case, please do so now.
- you have consumed the allowed amount of transactions and the app_id got deactivated. The time you looked for the status it was re-activated again due to reaching the anniversary date.