# HERE.com Destination Weather API using newly created API keys returns "Forbidden"

Tags: rest, here-api, weather-api

Currently, I, as a developer, am using the REST API key from my own "developer.here.com" project.

Now that the development is finished I need to replace my API key with the API key from my business partner. We have tried it with different accounts over the last few days but the result is always the same. Every request with newly created API keys returns
`{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}`. My API key is still working.

As I have seen other users with the same problem ([403 Forbidden - These credentials do not authorize access - weather here api forecast_astronomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072909/403-forbidden-these-credentials-do-not-authorize-access-weather-here-api-for) and [Here.com Destination Weather API returns "Forbidden" "These credentials do not authorize access"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64102737/here-com-destination-weather-api-returns-forbidden-these-credentials-do-not-a)) I thought time will solve the problem. But sadly it doesn't.

The accounts (email addresses) we've tried with are verified. And there can't be a problem with the quota because not a single request did work.

What we have tried:

- creating new HERE accounts and new API keys
- creating new API keys for the existing accounts
- creating an API key and then wait 3-4 days

Nothing works.

Sample request: [https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_hourly&latitude=48&longitude=16&apiKey={API-KEY}](https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_hourly&latitude=48&longitude=16&apiKey=%7BAPI-KEY%7D)

Comment: Are you using a key that has a domain restriction possibly?

Comment: No, there is no domain restriction with these REST API keys.

Comment: Can you share the full URL of your test? You can take away the key, but change it to like X. I want to be able to see exactly how you are calling the API.

Comment: @RaymondCamden good point. I added a sample request to the question

Comment: Using my key and it works just fine. Just to be super clear, you are not using { and } around your key, right? I assume not but want to be sure.

Comment: Also, to be clear, your key is coming from: Log into the dev portal, go to the REST section, go to API Keys, and you are copying the KEY, not the App ID.

Comment: @RaymondCamden yes exactly. to both question. My own API key is working fine too. The newly created API keys from my business partner are not working. And like I said: I also tried to create a new HERE account by myself and generate a new API key on my own, but this also doesn't work ...

Comment: Ok, drop me a line at raymond.camden@here.com. When you do, please include your key (if you feel safe doing so) and username. I'll pass it to my person who works on the portal.

Comment: Thank you for the offer. Because this problem was really time critical, sadly we had to switch to another weather provider.